# How to add event listener for a dynamically appended element's classList

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a div with the className `mic-button`, it is a dynamically appended element. I want to listen for change in it's `classList`, like, I want to trigger `function foo()` when any class is added or removed from the element. I prefer to use Vanilla Js. I searched in internet, and i only got solution with `JQUERY`.

Thanks, Rob Wilson

Comment: [ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) doesn't support events.

Comment: I mean, any tricky way to do so? like can i detect change in just attribute, and check if the attribute name is `class`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: but it seem not working in dynamically inserted elements

Comment: ?? [Just observe the parent](https://jsfiddle.net/f4Lm3sb0/1) of the dynamiclly inserted element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no event for this, but maybe you can check every second for changes in the ClassName.
Like this:

```js
var current = "mic-button";
window.setInterval(() => {
  var classN = document.querySelector(".mic-button").className;
  if (classN != current) {foo(); current = classN;}
}, 1000);

function foo() {
  console.log("foo");
 }
```

```html
<button class="mic-button">Mic-button</button><br />
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.mic-button').classList.add('foo');">add class</button><br />
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.mic-button').classList.remove('foo');">remove class</button>
```

Comment: does that slows down the website?

Comment: No, an if Statement every second shouldn't be a problem... Have got a website where i refresh something every second and it works perfectly

Comment: np ;) glad I could help

Comment: This is an awful solution, intervals are cumulating when the tab is not active, a Mutation Observer would be a better solution.